# How to get date and time in one place given the date and time in another place

Tags: vbscript

Is there an object that's part of standard Windows 7 that allows us to, within VBScript, get the local time in a given city/time zone?

One approach would be to use something like SWbemDateTime to convert a given time zone to UTC then re-convert back to another zone. Only the methods necessary to effect the latter step are not present on this particular object.

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple way to achieve this. You could try converting the time from localtime to UTC, [modify the timezone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944524), then convert the time from UTC back to localtime.

Answer (score 0):

Check out WMI class 'Win32_ComputerSystem' ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) property 'CurrentTimeZone' which returns the current 
time in UTC format.

Also the following classes could be referenced for UTC format:

1. Win32_Timezone - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394498(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Win32_UTCTime - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394510(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. Win32_LocalTime - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394171(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)